# JAVA - Parsing an XML file into Map using FasterXml.Jackson

Tags: java, xml, jackson, fasterxml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Site xmlns="bla" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  id="0" affiliations="foo" status="OPERATIONAL" color="#DB2253" updateTime="2002-12-17T09:30:47.0Z" name="GFB_0035" subject="GF">
    <location>
        <vertices Lat="41.905889" Lon="12.452019"/>
        <vertices Lat="41.905973" Lon="12.453596"/>
        <vertices Lat="41.905206" Lon="12.453707"/>
        <vertices Lat="41.905058" Lon="12.452109"/>
    </location>
</Site>
```

I am using `FasterXml.Jackson` to parse the data into a `Map<String, Object>`
object using the following code:

```
XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
Map<String, Object> data = xmlMapper.readValue(new File(xmlFile), Map.class);
```

However, when I look at the contents of the `"location"` field I have only one vertex instead of four (the last one).

**UPDATE:**
The map object which I get looks like the one bellow:

```
{id=0, affiliations=foo, status=OPERATIONAL, color=#DB2253, updateTime=2002-12-17T09:30:47.0Z, name=GFB_0035, subject=GF, location={vertices={Lat=41.905058, Lon=12.452109}}}
```

Is there a way to get all four entries using `FasterXml.Jackson`?

Comment: How does your output look like?

Comment: I've updated the question with the output of my code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) -

*A map cannot contain duplicate keys; each key can map to at most one value.*

And thats why when you look at the contents of the "location" field you have only one vertex instead of four (the last one).

I think you should parse the XML in your own classes instead of storing it into *Map*

See below example -

```
import java.io.IOException;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.XmlMapper;

public class Stack {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException {

        String xmlFile = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>"
                + "<Site xmlns=\"bla\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"  id=\"0\" affiliations=\"foo\""
                + " status=\"OPERATIONAL\" color=\"#DB2253\" updateTime=\"2002-12-17T09:30:47.0Z\" name=\"GFB_0035\" "
                + "subject=\"GF\">"
                + "    <location>"
                + "        <vertices lat=\"41.905889\" lon=\"12.452019\"/>"
                + "        <vertices lat=\"41.905973\" lon=\"12.453596\"/>"
                + "        <vertices lat=\"41.905206\" lon=\"12.453707\"/>"
                + "        <vertices lat=\"41.905058\" lon=\"12.452109\"/>"
                + "    </location>"
                + "</Site>";

        XmlMapper mapper = new XmlMapper();
        SiteData site = mapper.readValue(xmlFile, SiteData.class);
        System.out.println(site);
    }

}
```

SiteData.java

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.annotate.JacksonXmlProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.xml.annotate.JacksonXmlRootElement;

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "Site")
public class SiteData {

    private String id;

    private String affiliations;

    private String status;

    private String color;

    private String updateTime;

    private String name;

    private String subject;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "location")
    private LocationData location;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setIdValue(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAffiliations() {
        return affiliations;
    }

    public void setAffiliations(String affiliations) {
        this.affiliations = affiliations;
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public void setColor(String color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public String getUpdateTime() {
        return updateTime;
    }

    public void setUpdateTime(String updateTime) {
        this.updateTime = updateTime;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public LocationData getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(LocationData location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Site [id=" + id + ", affiliations=" + affiliations
                + ", status=" + status + ", color=" + color + ", updateTime="
                + updateTime + ", name=" + name + ", subject=" + subject
                + ", locations=" + location + "]";
    }
}
```

LocationData.java

```
import java.util.List;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.xml.annotation.JacksonXmlElementWrapper;

public class LocationData {

    @JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping=false)
    private List<VerticesData> vertices;

    public List<VerticesData> getVertices() {
        return vertices;
    }

    public void setVertices(List<VerticesData> vertices) {
        this.vertices = vertices;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "LocationData [vertices=" + vertices + "]";
    }

}
```

VerticesData.java

```
public class VerticesData {

    private String lat;

    private String lon;

    public String getLat() {
        return lat;
    }

    public void setLat(String lat) {
        this.lat = lat;
    }

    public String getLon() {
        return lon;
    }

    public void setLon(String lon) {
        this.lon = lon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Vertices [lat=" + lat + ", lon=" + lon + "]";
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Site [id=0, affiliations=foo, status=OPERATIONAL, color=#DB2253, updateTime=2002-12-17T09:30:47.0Z, name=GFB_0035, subject=GF, locations=LocationData [vertices=[Vertices [lat=41.905889, lon=12.452019], Vertices [lat=41.905973, lon=12.453596], Vertices [lat=41.905206, lon=12.453707], Vertices [lat=41.905058, lon=12.452109]]]]
```

Comment: Is there way that location will contain a list of the vertices?

Comment: Yes, That's what i suggest you write your custom class and parse XML to that class.

Comment: @ZachiShtain see updated answer, i have added example.