# Mapping xml attributes to java attributes

Tags: java, jaxb, fasterxml, jackson-dataformat-xml

```
Is there a way to map xml attributes to Java attributes using Jackson Faster xml.
Sample xml
<student>
 <details>
  <element key="firstName" value="John" />
  <element key="lastName" value="Doe" />
 </details>
</student>
```

The above xml needs to be mapped to below Java class.

```
public class Student {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
}
```

Comment: Have you searched for a possible solution yet? As this is not something that is particularly hard to find.

Comment: Yes, i have found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075306/java-parsing-an-xml-file-into-map-using-fasterxml-jackson, but this is more of a ArrayList of objects

Answer (score 0):

for such cases, I have written a static piece of code:

```
public static <T> T unmarshall(String xml, Class<T> clazz) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        T obj = clazz.cast(unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml)));
        return obj;
    }
```

Also annotate your DTO with:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@XmlRootElement(name = "<SomeName>")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Student {
private String firstName;
private String lastName;
}
```

After you have this method, you can use it to serialize your data:

```
Student studentResponse = (Student) unmarshall(response, Student.class);
```